# Partial Output while running python using flask

Tags: flask, jinja2, python-3.7

I am using flask for the first time, was doing some tutorials from youtube. I rechecked the code but didn't solve. The output of the last codes which is in "for" is not printing

Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello, World!'


@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return 'The About Page'


@app.route('/blog')
def blog():
    posts = [{'title': 'Technology in 2019', 'author': 'Sreeram'},
             {'title': 'Expansion of oil in Russia', 'author': 'Bob'}]
    return render_template('blog.html', author='bob', sunny=True)


@app.route('/blog/<string:blog_id>')
def blogpost(blog_id):
    return 'This is blog post number' + (blog_id)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>blog</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2> Welcome to this blog! </h2>
<p> I am Sreeram, the author of this blog </p>
{% if sunny %} -->
<p> Today it is sunny</p> -->
{% else %} -->
<p> Today it is rainy</p> -->
{% endif %} -->

{% for post in posts %}
    <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
    <h3>Author : {{post.author}}</h3>
{% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

I am getting output like this:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pY9kq.png)

Comment: you are not sending posts data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were not passing `posts` while rendering the template! Add `posts=posts` in the `render_template`!

**Like this:**

```
@app.route('/blog')
def blog():
    posts = [{'title': 'Technology in 2019', 'author': 'Sreeram'},
             {'title': 'Expansion of oil in Russia', 'author': 'Bob'}]
    return render_template('blog.html', author='bob', sunny=True, posts=posts)
```